# Need a public Subnet for each EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I'm recently learning ECS from AWS documents from [Module Two - Deploy the Monolith | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/break-monolith-app-microservices-ecs-docker-ec2/module-two/).

While I read the YAML file for the CloudFormation, the file creates two EC2 instances in the cluster and also specified two public subnets in the VPC. I'm new to the VPC, so is it because of the creation of 2 EC2 instances so two public subnets are needed?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: '2'
    Description: Number of instances to launch in your ECS cluster.
  MaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: '2'
    Description: Maximum number of instances that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues: [t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium, t2.large, m3.medium, m3.large,
      m3.xlarge, m3.2xlarge, m4.large, m4.xlarge, m4.2xlarge, m4.4xlarge, m4.10xlarge,
      c4.large, c4.xlarge, c4.2xlarge, c4.4xlarge, c4.8xlarge, c3.large, c3.xlarge,
      c3.2xlarge, c3.4xlarge, c3.8xlarge, r3.large, r3.xlarge, r3.2xlarge, r3.4xlarge,
      r3.8xlarge, i2.xlarge, i2.2xlarge, i2.4xlarge, i2.8xlarge]
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid instance type.
Mappings:
  AWSRegionToAMI:
    us-east-1:
      AMIID: ami-eca289fb
    us-east-2:
      AMIID: ami-446f3521
    us-west-1:
      AMIID: ami-9fadf8ff
    us-west-2:
      AMIID: ami-7abc111a
    eu-west-1:
      AMIID: ami-a1491ad2
    eu-central-1:
      AMIID: ami-54f5303b
    ap-northeast-1:
      AMIID: ami-9cd57ffd
    ap-southeast-1:
      AMIID: ami-a900a3ca
    ap-southeast-2:
      AMIID: ami-5781be34
  SubnetConfig:
    VPC:
      CIDR: '10.0.0.0/16'
    PublicOne:
      CIDR: '10.0.0.0/24'
    PublicTwo:
      CIDR: '10.0.1.0/24'
Resources:
  # VPC into which stack instances will be placed
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'VPC', 'CIDR']
  PublicSubnetOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
         Fn::Select:
         - 0
         - Fn::GetAZs: {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PublicOne', 'CIDR']
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  PublicSubnetTwo:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
         Fn::Select:
         - 1
         - Fn::GetAZs: {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PublicTwo', 'CIDR']
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  GatewayAttachement:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: GatewayAttachement
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref 'PublicRouteTable'
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
      GatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
  PublicSubnetOneRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetOne
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetTwoRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetTwo
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  # ECS Resources
  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
  EcsSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: ECS Security Group
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
  EcsSecurityGroupHTTPinbound:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '80'
      ToPort: '80'
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  EcsSecurityGroupSSHinbound:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '22'
      ToPort: '22'
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  EcsSecurityGroupALBports:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '31000'
      ToPort: '61000'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
  CloudwatchLogsGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Join ['-', [ECSLogGroup, !Ref 'AWS::StackName']]
      RetentionInDays: 14
  ECSALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: demo
      Scheme: internet-facing
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
        Value: '30'
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnetOne
        - !Ref PublicSubnetTwo
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup']
  ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PublicSubnetOne
        - !Ref PublicSubnetTwo
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref 'ContainerInstances'
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: !Ref 'MaxSize'
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref 'DesiredCapacity'
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT15M
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
        WillReplace: 'true'
  ContainerInstances:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [AWSRegionToAMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', AMIID]
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup']
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref 'EC2InstanceProfile'
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ECSCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
          yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
  ECSServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets'
              - 'ec2:Describe*'
              - 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress'
            Resource: '*'
  EC2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ec2.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ecs:CreateCluster'
              - 'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance'
              - 'ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint'
              - 'ecs:Poll'
              - 'ecs:RegisterContainerInstance'
              - 'ecs:StartTelemetrySession'
              - 'ecs:Submit*'
              - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
              - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              - 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'
              - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'
              - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
            Resource: '*'
  AutoscalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: service-autoscaling
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'application-autoscaling:*'
              - 'cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms'
              - 'cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm'
              - 'ecs:DescribeServices'
              - 'ecs:UpdateService'
            Resource: '*'
  EC2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles: [!Ref 'EC2Role']

Outputs:
  ClusterName:
    Description: The name of the ECS cluster, used by the deploy script
    Value: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
    Export:
      Name: !Join [':', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "ClusterName" ]]
  Url:
    Description: The url at which the application is available
    Value: !Join ['', [!GetAtt 'ECSALB.DNSName']]
  ALBArn:
    Description: The ARN of the ALB, exported for later use in creating services
    Value: !Ref 'ECSALB'
    Export:
      Name: !Join [':', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "ALBArn" ]]
  ECSRole:
    Description: The ARN of the ECS role, exports for later use in creating services
    Value: !GetAtt 'ECSServiceRole.Arn'
    Export:
      Name: !Join [':', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "ECSRole" ]]

VPCId:
  Description: The ID of the VPC that this stack is deployed in
  Value: !Ref 'VPC'
  Export:
    Name: !Join [':', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "VPCId" ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, two AZs are being used which requires two subnets (one for each AZ). This is not related to the number of EC2 instances.

A typical best practices with AWS and other cloud vendors is to use multiple availability zones (AZ) for fault tolerance. For AWS each AZ needs its own subnet. Auto scaling and load balancing will attempt to keep the number of instances the same in each AZ.

PS. If I was learning AWS, I would not start with this example. This example is very complex but very realistic for a real world deployment. There are lots of cloudformation examples that are much easy to master to start with.

Comment: Thanks very much.